# Why can't electric field lines intersect each other?

Tags: electric-fields

I just saw this on my textbook but I didn't quiet understand the thing can someone give an easy explanation.... Thanks

Comment: Did you try looking up the definition of a "field line"?  It is a tool we use to visualize fields and its definition might help address your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can two (or more) electric field lines never cross?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107171/)

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered before, but I'll try to give a simpler physical argument.

Suppose we put a charged particle in the electric field. The particle will experience a force due to the field and the direction of this force will always be parallel with the field line passing through the particle. Suppose the field had crossing field lines and we put our particle at one of the crossings. In which direction does the force point? Is is parallel with the first field line or with the other? There is no reason to choose one over the other and the force can't point in two directions at the same time, so there can't be crossing field lines.