# Why can't magnetic field lines intersect each other?

Tags: magnetic-fields

The sentence, "No two magnetic field lines can intersect each other." has always confused me. The tangent of a magnetic field line gives us the direction of the magnetic force. When two forces act in two different directions at a specified point, we can simply find out the resultant force by vector addition. Why can't I do that in this case?

Comment: General tip: Look in the right margin for related questions.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529997/247580 might help you

Answer (score 0):

If the magnetic field could cross how would know in which direction the field would be (as you said: The tangent of a magnetic field line gives us the direction of the magnetic force. In the case of intersecting there is not a unique direction of the field.
Of course, you can always find the resultant of two magnetic field vectors, but this result will always be part of a magnetic field line.

Answer (score 0):

A magnetic field line is a line whose direction at every point along it is the direction of the (*resultant*) field at that point. But at any point the resultant field can be only in one direction – otherwise it wouldn't be the resultant!

If we trace (using, perhaps a plotting compass) the field lines of a magnet, remove the magnet and place another one near where the first one was and trace *its* field lines, the two patterns will intersect. But with both magnets in place, the pattern (different from either plotted before) will contain no intersections: it will show the resultant field direction at each point.